# I have a applet script, how can I make it so if the variable goes over ex. 5, a picture shows up?

Tags: java, events, applet

I'm pretty sure I can figure out how to do add the picture (although if you know you can save me some research time on that), but how would I go on adding an event if variable bob is over 5?

```
package clicker;

import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class click extends Applet
{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Button increase, decrease; // These are two buttons
    int value = 0;

    public void init()
    {
        increase = new Button("Increase bob ");
        add(increase);
        decrease = new Button("Decrease bob ");
        add(decrease);
    }

    public boolean action(Event e, Object args)
    {
        if(e.target == increase)
            value++;
        if(e.target == decrease)
            value--;
        repaint();
        return true;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawString("How many bob do you give? " + value, 50, 80);
    }
}
```

Would I just add it into the public boolean action like the `e.target == increase`? I tried it and I had an error, I figured it would be in there. Where would I write it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Under your `action()` method, after you change the value variable, you would add another control statement.

```
if (value > 5) {
    new ImageIcon(new URL("image/path")).paintIcon(this, getGraphics(), x, y);
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, it seems it works, but what do I put in the image/path? I know the path for the image, but if I build it, how can it find it on others pc :/? if the name for the image file is Bob.png, what do I do? Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean? Starting with the easier answer, if the image is in the same folder as the applet's code, you'd replace "image/path" with "Bob.png." If you need to find the image for Bob on somebody else's computer, I'm not sure I know how to do that